# Access data in laravel

Tags: laravel

I need to access data on my view. can you assist me in reviewing my code its throwing me an error massage: "Trying to get property 'avatar' of non-object"

My controller:

```
        $user = User::find($id);
        $profile = Personal_Details::select('*')->where('user_id', $id)->first();
        //return $profile;
        $idd = $user->id;
        $name = $user->name;
        $email = $user->email;
        $avatar = $user->avatar;
        $lastname = $profile->lastname;
        $cellNumber = $profile->cellNumber;
        $street = $profile->address_street;
        $city = $profile->address_city;
        $province = $profile->address_province;
        $postal = $profile->address_postal_code;

        $records = array(['id'=>$idd, 'avatar'=>$avatar, 'name'=>$name." ".$lastname,'email'=>$email, 'cellnumber'=>$cellNumber, 'address1'=>$street.", ".$city, 'address2'=>$province.", ".$postal]);
        $record = $records[0];
        // return $record;
        return view('admin.profile.specialist')->with(['record'=>$record]);
```

My view:

```
             <div class="px-4 pt-0 pb-4 bg-dark">
                <div class="media align-items-end profile-header" style="padding-top: 5%">
                    <div class="profile mr-3"><img src="/storage/avatars/{{ $record->avatar }}" alt="..." width="130" class="rounded mb-2 img-thumbnail"><a href="{{ route('admin.profile.edit', Auth::user()->id) }}" class="btn btn-light btn-sm btn-block">Edit profile</a></div>
                    <div class="media-body mb-4 text-white">
                        <h4 class="mt-0 mb-0">{{ $record->name }}</h4>
                        <p class="small mb-4"> 
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope mr-2"></i>{{ $record->email }}<br>
                            <i class="fa fa-phone mr-2"></i>{{ $record->cellnumber }}<br>
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker mr-2"></i>{{ $record->address1 }},<br> {{ $record->address2 }}<br>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-switch text-white">
                        <div class="row">
                            <a hrt="" style="padding-right:43px">Personal</a>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Business</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

my response when i uncomment return $record:

```
{"id":2,"avatar":"default.jpg","name":"Test Data","email":"example@example.io","cellnumber":"0711234567","address1":"1002 Highway, Geelong","address2":"Melbe, 21910"}
```

I'm not sure what i have missed or maybe the way m trying to access code is wrong.

Comment: `$record` is declared as an array, not an object. `$record['avatar']` should work but your code is very redundant.

Comment: can you help with optimising it, or offer suggestions

Comment: Alright. I'll offer my two cents in an answer below.

Comment: Since `$record` is an associative array, in your view instead of using `$record->property` you should use `$record['property']`
for example to get the avatar you should use `$record['avatar']`

and as @IGP said your code is redundant, you should consider looking at Eloquent Relationships at https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: @IGP Thanks, will definitely look into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Trying to get property 'avatar' of non-object"

This means you're using a variable as an object when it's something else (aray, string, null, etc). This happens in your case because of the following lines

```
$records = array(['id'=>$idd, 'avatar'=>$avatar, 'name'=>$name." ".$lastname,'email'=>$email, 'cellnumber'=>$cellNumber, 'address1'=>$street.", ".$city, 'address2'=>$province.", ".$postal]);
$record = $records[0];
```

`$record` is an array here. `$record->avatar` will throw the error. `$record['avatar']` will access the `avatar` key of the `$record` array.

But that is a bit redundant because you've already got all the information you need in the `$user` and `$profile` variables. `$records` and `$record` have no reason to exist.

```
$user = User::find($id);
$profile = Personal_Details::select('*')->where('user_id', $id)->first();

return view('admin.profile.specialist', compact('user', 'profile');
```

`$user` and `$profile` are objects so you can use them as such in your view.

```
<div class="px-4 pt-0 pb-4 bg-dark">
  <div class="media align-items-end profile-header" style="padding-top: 5%">
    <div class="profile mr-3">
      <img src="/storage/avatars/{{ $user->avatar }}" alt="..." width="130" class="rounded mb-2 img-thumbnail">
      <a href="{{ route('admin.profile.edit', Auth::user()->id) }}" class="btn btn-light btn-sm btn-block">Edit profile</a>
    </div>
    <div class="media-body mb-4 text-white">
      <h4 class="mt-0 mb-0">{{ $user->name }}</h4>
      <p class="small mb-4"> 
        <i class="fa fa-envelope mr-2"></i>{{ $user->email }}<br>
        <i class="fa fa-phone mr-2"></i>{{ $profile->cellnumber }}<br>
        <i class="fa fa-map-marker mr-2"></i>{{ $profile->address_street}}, {{ $profile->address_city }},<br> {{ $profile->address_province }}, {{ $profile->address_postal_code }}<br>
        <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-switch text-white">
      <div class="row">
        <a href="" style="padding-right:43px">Personal</a>
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Business</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And that's it. The following might not apply to you, so feel free to ignore.

The query `Personal_Details::where('user_id', $user->id)->get()` suggests a [One-to-one](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) relationship.

You could declare it and then use it in your controller/view.

```
# User model
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Personal_Detail::class, 'user_id');
}
```

```
# Personal_Detail model
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

```
# Controller
$user = User::with('profile')->find($id);

return view('admin.profile.specialist', compact('user');
```

And then in your view, you could replace `$profile->...` by `$user->profile->...`